# Python: Creating a Maze - Possible issues as windows auto-close

Tags: python

I currently have Python 3.4 installed (issues prevented me from successfully installing Python 3.5) and I am trying to run two scripts which takes a users input then creates a maze based off of the provided coordinates.

The issues I am facing is, the first script which should wait for user to type 
    makeMaze(x,y)

doesn't even do that and just auto closes. 
Everything below 'def makeMaze' is still in that function, but formatting might mess up.

When I use breakpoints, it just goes to the 'def makeMaze' then quits after that.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

```
from graphics import *
from Maze import *
import random

PROBABILITY = 0.60;


def makeMaze(rows, columns):
    # Create the display window
    win = GraphWin ("Maze Test", 10 * (columns + 1), 10 * (rows + 1))

    # Set up the full maze
    board = Maze (rows, columns)

    # Calculate the board center and put it in as the starting point
    r0 = rows // 2
    c0 = columns // 2
    board.set (r0, c0, START)
    queue = []
    queue.append(Point(r0, c0))

    while len(queue) > 0:  # As long as there are things to process in the queue
        element = queue.pop(0)  # Get the next location
        r = element.getX()
        c = element.getY()

        r1 = r + 2   # Move down two and see if we can cut a corridor
        if board.onMap (r1, c) and board.get(r1, c) == ROCK and random.random() < PROBABILITY:
            board.set(r+1, c, OPEN)
            board.set(r1, c, OPEN)
            queue.append(Point(r1, c))
            r1 = r - 2   # Move up two and see if we can cut a corridor
        if board.onMap (r1, c) and board.get(r1, c) == ROCK and random.random() < PROBABILITY:
            board.set(r-1, c, OPEN)
            board.set(r1, c, OPEN)
            queue.append(Point(r1, c))
            c1 = c + 2   # Move right two and see if we can cut a corridor
    if board.onMap (r, c1) and board.get(r, c1) == ROCK and random.random() < PROBABILITY:
        board.set(r, c+1, OPEN)
        board.set(r, c1, OPEN)
        queue.append(Point(r, c1))        
        c1 = c - 2   # Move left two and see if we can cut a corridor
    if board.onMap (r, c1) and board.get(r, c1) == ROCK and random.random() < PROBABILITY:
            board.set(r, c-1, OPEN)
            board.set(r, c1, OPEN)
        queue.append(Point(r, c1))

# Starting at one of the four sides, place the exit
side = random.randint(0,3)
if side == 0:   # Top edge
    steps = columns // 2
    cStart = 1 + 2 * random.randint(0, (steps // 2))
    rStart = 0
    board.set (0, cStart, EXIT)
    dRow = 1
    dCol = 0
elif side == 1:  # Bottom edge
    steps = columns // 2
    cStart = 1 + 2 * random.randint(0, (steps // 2))
    size = board.getSize()
    rStart, c1 = size
    rStart-=1
    board.set (rStart, cStart, EXIT)
    dRow = -1
    dCol = 0 
elif side == 2:  # Left edge
    steps = rows // 2
    rStart = 1 + 2 * random.randint(0, (steps // 2))
    cStart = 0
    board.set (rStart, 0, EXIT)
    dRow = 0
    dCol = 1
else:            # Right Edge
    steps = rows // 2
    rStart = 1 + 2 * random.randint(0, (steps // 2))
    size = board.getSize()
    r1, cStart = size
    cStart-=1
    board.set (rStart, cStart, EXIT)
    dRow = 0
    dCol = -1 

# Cut a corridor inward from the exit until you contact the maze
rStart += dRow
cStart += dCol
while board.get(rStart, cStart) == ROCK:
    board.set (rStart, cStart, OPEN)
    rStart += dRow
    cStart += dCol

# Display the maze and wait for the person to click
board.display (10, win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Comment: ..where is `makeMaze` being called?

Comment: What I expect it to do to for it to wait for the user to type 'makeMake(23,23)' and then it pushes those to the function.

Comment: Ok, does it ever get inside the function? I asked because if not, it could be a problem with however you are intending to call the function.

Comment: It will work only if you do it in IDLE, and you will have to type in the whole script each time, so it's probably not a good solution. Wait a second, I'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an impression that you only made programs using IDLE. In IDLE, after executing the code you gave in your question, user can just type in `makeMaze(23,23)` and it will call the function. But if you put it in a file, it won't just execute what the user types. You will have to do something like this,

```
w = int(input('Type in the width: '))
h = int(input('Type in the height: '))
makeMaze(w, h)
```

user will type in width, press enter, type in height, press enter, and the fuction will be called.

If you want to make user input width and height at the same time (with space as a delimeter), you can do it like this

```
w, h = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

or like that

```
w, h = map(int, input().split())
```

and then call `makeMaze()`

```
makeMaze(w, h)
```

Comment: I definitely see where you are going - I have implemented the first solution however it comes back with the error: "makeMaze" is not defined. Which confuses me further since directly below I have "def makeMaze(rows,columns):'.

Error is: builtins.NameError: name 'makeMaze' is not defined

Comment: You're referencing makeMaze before it's defined. Put the call to makeMaze() after the definition.

Comment: Kal was exactly right. I am not used to the order playing a part and was calling before it was defined. Thank you very much to the both of you! :)